# How to UN-escape html strings

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, string

So I have a database table that stores pre-escaped text strings (don't ask me why ... I don't know) and I need to put it on the page as a RAW string.  All of the rails output functions seems to escape the output.

ex
`<%= @string %>`  will escape the string's special characters before printing to the screen

So if I have the string `&amp;`  I end up with something like `&amp;amp;` and the output to the screen is simply `&amp;`

Comment: indeed it is, I couldn't find it before you posted it though.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `raw` method:

```
<%= raw @string %>
```