# Disable html escaping in a helper function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping, view-helpers

i have created in my application_helper a define for a standard link_to like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def foo_link_to(text, path)
      out = "<span class=\"span\">"
      out += link_to text, path
      out += "</span>"
      out
    end
end
```

and in my partial i have

```
<%= foo_link_to 'text', home_path %>
```

but this is my output

```
&lt;span class=&quot;span&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/home&quot;&gt;index&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
```

now, my question is: where i need to insert the html_escape?
ty all

Thanks at all for the support.
Now i have another issue...if i wont this output what i have to do?

```
<a href="home.html"><i class="iclass"></i><span class="span"> text </span></a>
```

Using `raw out` and `out.html_safe` the output is

```
a href="/home">/home</a>&lt;span class=&quot;span&quot;&gt;&lt;i class=&quot;iclass&quot;&gt;text&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `raw`, in your last line

```
raw out
```

And your helper can be further refactored as

```
def foo_link_to(text, path)
  content_tag :span do
    link_to text, path
  end
end
```

I forget but it seems you don't need `raw` in the later case.

Update: For the last icon one, you can output like this

```
link_to 'home.html' do
  content_tag :i, class: 'iclass'
  content_tag :span, class: 'span' do
    'Text'
  end
end
```

Comment: @gotva, thanks for the edit. I think `class="span"` makes no sense in CSS so I havn't included it in the later version :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def foo_link_to(text, path)
    out = "<span class=\"span\">"
    out += link_to text, path
    out += "</span>"
    out.html_safe
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should insert raw o html_safe in last line

Answer (score 0):

`html_safe` can help you:

use `out.html_safe`

you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273349/how-to-un-escape-html-strings/19273582#19273582)